# R function not returning modified data table

Tags: r, function

I have the following data table called "grams2_test_freq":

```
str(grams2_test_freq)
 Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 191026 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ term: chr  "and_green" "green_acknowledged" "acknowledged_friday" "friday_there" ...
 $ c   : num  6 1 1 1 69 4 1 7 12 3 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Where "term" are various N-grams, and "c" is their frequency count.

I want to create a function that adds a column to the data table, containing the probability occurrence of each 'term' within the entire data table  --so that I can apply the function to any data table I want.

I have tried the simple code below using the dply MUTATE command -it does work whilst the function is running, but once the function ends, the data table that is in the R environment hasn't changed at all (the Probability column has not been added):

```
calc.prob.all.words.in.test.set <- function(test_set)   {
             test_set <- mutate(test_set, Probability = c /sum(c) )  
                                                        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks...!

Comment: There is nothing wrong.in the function. Perhaps you need to return the 'test_set'. Changing the object within the function, wouldn't change the object in the global env

Comment: You shouldn't have to return `test_set`, since the assignment should be invisibly returning the results from `mutate` ... which should be the entire/updated frame. It would help, Thruinin, if you provided *how* you're using this function.

Comment: maybe try `calc.prob.all.words.in.test.set <- function(test_set) test_set[, Probability := c /sum(c)][] `

Comment: Thanks akrun r2evans and chinsoon12.  What happens is the test_set is only modified in the local function environment and not in the Global Environment. I will then use the output of this function inside another function with which I will calculate the perplexity of a corpus. Thanks again!